# Confusion in AWS S3 IOS sdk?

Tags: iphone, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have an IPhone application in which I like to include IOS sdk for s3. I have doubts whether getobject requests can be used for streaming an audio file from s3 to my app. Everybody saying it is for download. Not for stream. Is there any other method in this sdk for streaming only. So that I don't want to download the files. I just need to stream the url of my audio file from s3 and play it on the avaudioplayer.

```
s3Client = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];              
S3GetObjectRequest *request = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:@"YOURKEY" withBucket:@"YOURBUCKET"];
S3GetObjectResponse *response = [s3Client getObject:request];
```

is it enough?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32111029/2265218
can you please help me for the above question ?

Answer (score 1):

I think apple's http live streaming can help you.Please find the details in followings link.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: If you have an audio file in S3, then you can create a URL corresponding to it as like below
 `https://<region>.amazonaws.com/<bucket-name>/<key>`
From this URL you can stream content using avaudioplayer.